# qemu KVM audio not working on guest OS

Tags: centos, audio, kvm, qemu

i'm not getting audio from a guest os. i'm using virt-manager. following are my settings : Guest OS(Cloudera (CentOS 6.7)) , Display Spice, Sound ich6 and video QXL. can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Is the soundcard detected in the guest? check `dmesg` and `lspci`, and [Edit-in](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/330404/edit) relevant parts of the output of your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching through http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Guest_Support_Status#CentOS i found out that centOS(6.7) is not yet supported. So i have switched to VMWare Workstation.